# Any drug in which the withdrawal is fatal and thus requires regular consumption (after the first dose)?

Tags: drug-metabolism, chemical, drug-withdrawal

Is there any drug/medicine which once assumed forces you to take regular doses to avoid death? In example a light version of that should be insulin (Probably I'm mistaken, but I've read that taking insulin increases insulin resistance which makes you even more dependent on the medicine to avoid the damage of sugar).

I'm not asking only for substances that causes a real addiction (urgent need to take even more doses), but substances that may cause that in a silent way.

It is not necessary that the person makes a long use of that drug, but I prefer drugs that achieve that effect with short or minimal usage. I'm asking out of curiosity, because I've read of fictional drugs (Melange in Dune) doing that and I just know discovering that in reality many drugs have that or similar effects.

Comment: I've read abuse of common substances may be lethal once someone fall in withdrawal (alcol, benzos and opiates) however this require a long abuse of that substances, I'm interested in more exotic substances and on substances with quick effects (still information on the afore mentioned substances is wellcome if provided with reliable sources)

Comment: Ever heard of this one - water?

Comment: Nope, water is needed by "our nature"... " which once assumed forces you to take regular doses to avoid death" .. If you never assume water you just die, there is not need for "first dose".